# PhoneGap Project Armv6

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, armv6

I built a Phonegap 2.0.1 project, and under the build settings for the CordovaLib.ecodeproj it says

```
Architectures: Standard (armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) 
Valid Architectures: 1386 armv7 armv7
```

However Under the build settings for my projects .xcodeproj I have

```
Architectures: Standard (armv6, armv7)
Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7
```

So they seem to contradict each other :S.

The main problem is PhoneGap has dropped support for armv6 however under the current settings the app installs and loads up fine on armv6 devices such as the iphone 3g, but hangs pretty soon in :(.

I tried changing my projects build settings to:

```
Architectures: Standard (armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
```

However this caused xcode to start screaming about some error in the CordovaLib files :S

What should the correct settings be here, I dont want people to install my app on armv6 and have it crash on them :(, how do I ensure only armv7 devices are able to install it

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Xcode are you using? PhoneGap has dropped support for older versions because Apple has - To publish something on the app store you need to support iOS6, which means using the latest version of Xcode and not supporting armv6.

Since $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) is the default setting for native iOS projects, not just PhoneGap, I think you can count on the app store system to only deploy to supported devices.